# Getting results for even years only

Tags: ssas, mdx, iccube

MDX has a nice feature whereby I can specify a range of members:

```
SELECT ([Canada],[2006]:[2011]) on Rows,
      [Measures].members on Columns
FROM [Sales]
```

Is there a way to calculate the set of even years: `{[2006], [2008], [2010]}`? I am looking for a way that would work for large sets, so that listing the years manually is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter you function using a [filter function](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Filter.php), a [declared function](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Declared%20Functions.php) and [MOD function](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Excel%20Numerical%20Functions.php) (MOD returns the remainder from the division - like % in Java ) :

```
WITH
  FUNCTION isEven(Value _number) as Mod( Int(_number) , 2 ) = 0
SELECT
  FILTER( [Date].[Date].[Year] as t, isEven( Year( t.current.key) ) )  on 0
FROM [Cube]
```

If you are using this filter often you could create a FilterEven declared function once in the script (same for isEven() )

Comment: This does not work in icCube (the sample Sales cube). `Year()` results in NULL exception.

Comment: I think for this cube the year key is a string not a date, change Year() function to CLong() or if the key is already an integer to nothing. https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Excel%20Conversion%20Functions.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I used adventure works for the query.For the mod logic i took help from 
[Mod Logic](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18186.mod-function-in-mdx.aspx)

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Data Type] AS 
[Date].[Day of Year].CurrentMember.Properties ("Member_Value",TYPED) 

MEMBER [Measures].[IsEven] as
[Measures].[Data Type]-Int([Measures].[Data Type]/2)*2 

select {[Measures].[Internet Order Count]  }
on columns,
filter (
[Date].[Day of Year].[Day of Year],
[Measures].[IsEven]=0)
 on rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

Answer (score 0):

Plus you can have a column in the date dimension have 1,0 to indicate if the year is even or odd. Then simply use that column in the MDX query , no need to do all the above manipulations